# With jQuery why is document not passed as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery why is document not passed as a string to select it like everything else and is there anything else that isn't passed as a string?

For example if I have an h1 element.

```
$("document").click(function(){
  $("h1").after("<p>lorem ipsum</p>"); //doesn't work
})

$(document).click(function(){
  $("h1").after("<p>lorem ipsum</p>"); //works
})
```

Comment: a string is put into the document.querySelectorAll method. It searches inside of the document. So document.querySelectorAll("document") returns an empty collection

Comment: jQuery accepts a String (usually a CSS Selector) or a DOM Node as parameter to create a jQuery Object. `document` is a DOM Node, `"h1"` is a string that is a selector. `"document"` is neither a selector nor a DOM Node.

Comment: The `jQuery` function is overloaded to receive different argument types that do different strings. You're allowed to directly pass elements or the document, and a new jQuery object will be created that references those nodes. When passing a string, it needs to be analyzed to see if you intended a selector string, or some HTML for the purpose of creating new elements. When passing a function, it will invoke it when (or if) the page is loaded.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `<document>` tag is another way to answer this. Without a css selector prefix you are looking for such a tag and it doesn't exist

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, document is a DOM Node that cannot be accessed by a *CSS selector*. I wonder if its the only one!

Comment: @sabithpocker: Text nodes, comment nodes, attribute nodes and `window` are some others.

Comment: because "document" as a string is not a valid selector for the document object. You can use body: $("body").click(function(){ alert("click");})

Comment: Or `"html"` will give you the `document.documentElement` if you really want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document` is a variable in JavaScript (comes from `window.document`, but `window` is default scope). Wrapping it with the jQuery Selector transforms it into a jQuery object.

If you use a string then jQuery thinks you gave it a selector. jQuery (or JavaScript actually) tries to find the element in the DOM but there is no such element in the DOM of type "document" hence it fails.

Comment: *jQuery Object. Theres not sth like a jquery variable

Comment: I wrote Javascript, not jQuery. It's a variable in Javascript. The type of the variable is object.

Comment: Sorry I forgot what I wrote already, thanks for correcting.

Comment: *"`document` is a variable in JavaScript"* ... not completely accurate. Only in a browser

Answer (score 0):

Because document is a property of window and is an Object.
You can check by logging it out `console.log(window.document)`

The jQuery selector function selects a valid select as a string or a Dom Node Object. `$("document")` won't work because there is no element called document. `$(document)` or `$(window.document)` will work because it is a valid Dom Node.

If first you ran `document.createElement('document')` to create an element called document then `$("document")` would work but you would be select the new element and not window.document

Comment: theres a bit of explanation missing ( why does $("document") not work)...